# Coordinates translation issue (from EPSG:23030 to EPSG:4326)

Tags: postgis, javascript, translation, proj4js

I'm trying to figure out how to make some translations from UTM/ED50 to WGS84.

The reason I need to do them is that my data source's coordinates are in EPSG:23030 format, and I need to represent them in a map, currently using leaflet, which needs every coordinates to be in WGS84.

I've been using Postgis' raw sql queries to transform coordinates, as follows:

```
SELECT ST_AsText(ST_Transform(ST_GeomFromText('POINT(581087 4796507)', 23030), 4326));
```

That query returns me the following:

```
"POINT(-2.0013194711113 43.3151520669395)"
```

[image: good coord]

As I'm developing a web project using html+js and so on, I needed some library to make translations. So I found proj4js, and I can make translations as follows:

```
proj4.defs([
    [
        'EPSG:4326', 
        '+title=WGS 84 (long/lat) +proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +units=degrees'
    ],
    [
        'EPSG:23030',
        '+title=ED50 (UTM) +proj=utm +zone=30 +ellps=intl +units=m +no_defs'
    ]
]);

var coord = proj4('EPSG:23030', 'EPSG:4326').forward([581087,4796507]);
```

holding coord the following coordinate:

```
43.315428738109816, -2.000074748128657
```

[image: wrong coordinate]

So the question is why am I getting different coordinates, knowing that I'm -seemingly- using the same coordinate systems to make the translation in PostGis and in Proj4js? Is there something wrong?

As far as I know, the right conversion corresponds to PostGis.

Comment: The PostGIS towgs84 values are the generic ones for ED50 to WGS84. A more accurate one for Spain is a 7 parameter one: -131.0,-100.3,-163.4,-1.244,-0.02,-1.144,9.39 AKA EPSG:1633. If you want to stick with a 3 parameter one, EPSG:1145, -84,-107,-120.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check the proj definition stored in the spatial_ref_sys, it should be different from the one used in the proj4js definition.

For example, mine is the following:

`+proj=utm +zone=30 +ellps=intl +towgs84=-87,-98,-121,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs`

Also epsg.io gives the one with the towgs84 parameters, so I'd change the Proj4js def.

Comment: Query to use is `select proj4text from spatial_ref_sys
where srid=23030;`